How can I fix the error "worksuite-sass-new not installed"?
Recently, I have downloaded laravel project, but when I tried to run the project on server, "worksuite-sass-new not installed" error occured.

I tried to install worksuite-sass but I can not login to cpanel. But I can't make sure this is the right solution. I expect to fix the error.
